# how to get the current date from wildfly 10 server and convert it into int?

Tags: java, timer

I'm working with a Wildfly Jboss 10 server application. I'm making an auction web site and need the create a time for them(the auction expires after 2 days).. I was thinking on a programmatic timer
Here's what I've done till now:

```
  public void setTimer() {
    int finalInt = 0;
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    finalInt += dayOfWeek + 2;
    Date dateFinal = new Date(finalInt);
    Timer timer = timerService.createSingleActionTimer(dateFinal, new TimerConfig());
}

@Timeout
public void programmaticTimeout(Timer timer) {
    this.setLastProgrammaticTimeout(new Date());
    logger.info("Programmatic timeout occurred.");
}
```

It doesn't work, and a get a warning for Calendar saying:

```
Could not load declaring class: timeout.TimerSessionBean of timeout method
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.CalendarTimer.getTimeoutMethod(CalendarTimer.java:299)
```

I was thinking to get the current date from server and convert it into int, instead of doing this with Calendar class.

Can someone help me, please ? It's possible to do this ?